# MySQL database Nodejs, initial tables query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am creating a Nodejs MySQL database website. I have decided what schemas I need for a bunch of tables. As of right now I am using the mysql workbench to create tables and connecting to mysql database. Should I store all the create table schemas in a folder somewhere in Nodejs and run it using node and mysql package?. Should I use it to create new tables in production as I will be wiping all data fairly often? I have found very little directions online on how this is usually done.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All your concerns have been previously answered by **Database Migration** concept.

Database migration takes care of initialization of your schema with tables. It also takes care of production.

Check out [db-migrate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/db-migrate). Its a popular db migration tool in node.js.

It helps you create automation scripts.
Also check out this [excellent tutorial](https://itnext.io/updating-an-sql-database-schema-using-node-js-6c58173a455a) for a step by step guide

Comment: This was pretty helpful but I want to do more than just track schema change made to the database. Is there a way to also revert back the data. If I change data of my dev database while I am testing various things and than want to pull all the data and the schema of the database that is deployed

Comment: db migration also takes care of synchronising multiple databases including dev and production. But reverting data back is completely another concern. You must have a backup plan which can be done with most databases directly. For example schedule backup every day and apply a previous backup if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the info I will look into it further

Answer (score 2):

[Knex](https://knexjs.org) is good solution for database migrations:

You have to set up your enviroment connection/database at `knexfile.js`:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: 'migrations'
  }
});
```

Then at `/migrations` create the desired initial tables:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('user', function (table) {
       table.increments('id');
       table.string('first_name', 255).notNullable();
       table.string('last_name', 255).notNullable();
    })
    .createTable('product', function (table) {
       table.increments('id');
       table.decimal('price').notNullable();
       table.string('name', 1000).notNullable();
    });
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema
      .dropTable("product")
      .dropTable("user");
};
```

To create the tables use the following command:

```
$> knex migrate:latest
```

Find more information at https://knexjs.org/#Installation-migrations